# Yii2 - $changedAttributes for numbers (typecasting?)

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, typecasting-operator

I have a form with a `price` column with mysql type Decimal that can be null. My model is set up as follows:

```
use yii\behaviors\AttributeTypecastBehavior;

class Item extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [                
            ['amount', 'integer'],
            ['price', 'number'],
            ['is_active', 'boolean'],
        ];
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'typecast' => [
                'class' => AttributeTypecastBehavior::className(),               
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function afterSave($insert,$changedAttributes)
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert,$changedAttributes);
        print_r($changedAttributes); // shows the number attributes as being changed when they have not actually changed

    // ...
}
```

How do I set up my model so that the `price` attribute really has changed in `afterSave()`? It seems to work with the `amount` (integer) attribute.

Comment: Default validator requires `value` to be set.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it - (I modified the question to reflect).

Comment: Does it work if you put the default rule as last?

Comment: No :s I tried removing the default rule, seems to have no effect.. `amount` works but `price` doesn't.

Comment: You are trying to set `null` value which usually means that there should be no change for the attribute. Maybe override `beforeSave()` and if `price` is empty set it to `null`.

Comment: Thanks but tried it even without the default rule values and still get the same result. I'm guessing it must be something to do with typecasting 'number' (or mysql decimal values) and how they're handled as strings, but no idea how to fix.

Comment: So setting `null` in `beforeSave` doesn't work either?

Comment: Tried it and.. say my database original price value is 104.50. In `beforeSave()` if I set `$this->price = '104.50'`, then it correctly doesn't show up in `$changedAttributes`. I tried `$this->price = (string) $this->price;` but that incorrectly shows up in $changedAttributes

Comment: I don't understand... so you don't want this to be null anymore?

Comment: I still do, but having it there or not doesn't seem to affect anything

Comment: Please update your question with the steps to reproduce and expected result.

Comment: I removed the AttributeTypecastBehavior altogether, didn't seem to help.  The price attribute continues to show up in `$changedAttributes`, but I do a soft compare - ie. if `$changedAttributes['price'] != $this->price`, etc.. (rather than `!==` operator) to check if it really has changed.